# How to print out an iterator for a set of sets

Tags: c++, iterator, set

I have made a code that should construct a set of sets. However, when I use an iterator to try to print out the set obtained, I run into an error. 
This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    set<long> A, B, C;

    for (long k=1; k<4; k++) A.insert(k);   // A={1, 2, 3}
    for (long k=4; k<6; k++) B.insert(k);   // B={4, 5}
    C.insert(6);                            // C={6}

    set< set<long> > S;       // Now implement S as a set of  finite sets
    S.insert(A);
    S.insert(B);
    S.insert(C);

    /** Finally, print out S using an iterator si: **/

    set< set<long> >::const_iterator si;

    for (si=S.begin(); si !=S.end(); si)
    {
        cout << *si << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If I comment the line starting with cout,  the program builds without error. However, there is an error on this line because if I try to build the computer refuses it and I get the following error message: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << si.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator* >()'|

Now I am pretty new to this, but I suspect if the error has something to do with the fact that I should redefine the operator "<<"? Or what?
What should I do to fix the code and print out the set?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to do? what output are you looking for?

Comment: You are in. You need to implement << operator to print set.

Comment: Thanks Velthune. But how should I do it?? Just to make sure, I started to work on C++ one week ago... :(

Comment: The answer, read the answer.

Comment: You need that for legacy c++, or c++ >= c++11?

Comment: @RandomGuy I explain you how to use inheritance and ostream overloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the inner set:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
set<long> A, B, C;

for (long k = 1; k<4; k++) A.insert(k);   // A={1, 2, 3}
for (long k = 4; k<6; k++) B.insert(k);   // B={4, 5}
C.insert(6);                            // C={6}

set< set<long> > S;       // Now implement S as a set of  finite sets
S.insert(A); S.insert(B); S.insert(C);

/** Finally, print out S using an iterator si: **/

set< set<long> >::const_iterator si;
set<long>::const_iterator si2;

for (si = S.begin(); si != S.end(); ++si)
{
    for (si2 = si->begin(); si2 != si->end(); ++si2)
    {
        cout << *si2 << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;

return 0;
}
```

The C++ 11 11 answer is more elegant:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
set<long> A, B, C;

for (long k = 1; k<4; k++) A.insert(k);   // A={1, 2, 3}
for (long k = 4; k<6; k++) B.insert(k);   // B={4, 5}
C.insert(6);                            // C={6}

set< set<long> > S;       // Now implement S as a set of  finite sets
S.insert(A); S.insert(B); S.insert(C);

/** Finally, print out S using an iterator si: **/

for (auto si : S)
{
    for (auto si2 : si)
    {
        cout << si2 << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should create another iterator to iterate through inner set:

```
set<long>::iterator in;
```

And use both iterators like this:

```
for(si = S.begin(); si != S.end(); ++si)
  for(in = si->begin(); in != si->end(); ++in)
    std::cout << *in << " ";
```

Because each item inside si is another set, that can contain several long variables.

Comment: `si` here is your `set< set<long> >::const_iterator` and `S` is your set of sets. Output is contents inside each set A,B,C ;).
You can formatt it with adding for eq. `std::cout << std::endl;` in outer for loop.

Comment: I have tried but now indeed it prints out  1 2 3 4 5 6. This in some sense it is ok, but it is not clear how to make the program to print the elements to make them appear they are sets. 

In other words,  Iwould like to print out something like:  123  45  6, to make it appear that the elements of the set S are themselves sets. Any idea about how to do it?

Comment: Yes, I had figured out that s was standing for si, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution, not *the* solution:

```
class LongSet: public set<long> {

    // Here can choose custom way to print out your set.
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const LongSet& matrix) {
        set<long>::iterator i = this.begin();
        for (; i != this.end(); ++i) {
           stream << *i << " ";
        } 
        return stream
    }

}
```

In this way, your code will be:

```
set< LongSet >::const_iterator si;

for (si=S.begin(); si !=S.end(); si){
   cout << *si << " ";  
}
```